# PHP objects that stay in memory

Tags: php

I recall reading on [php.net](http://php.net) (although unfortunately can't seem to find the page) that the PHP interpreter can run in different ways - most commonly, every time a page is requested, an instance of the PHP interpreter is created, runs its course, and then is destroyed, along with all the memory associated with that particular page call. Apparently, it is also possible to allow all the memory to linger, so that it can be used again in future page calls; as I understood it, essentially allowing multiple different PHP scripts to access and modify the same objects, without losing them after the script is complete.

Or at least, so I remember. Is there any truth to this? If so, how would I set it up?

Comment: What are you trying to solve? What is the original issue?

Comment: Maybe the $_SESSION variable is all you need :)

Comment: If you want to persist objects in memory, then cache them in APC or Memcached. But yes, maybe you're just looking for session functionality.

Comment: There are shared memory methods http://php.net/manual/en/book.shmop.php But it is still serializing and unserializing objects

Comment: @zerkms: I was intending to use this to create an application that is constantly sending and receiving information from other servers (through basic GET and POST), and will need to be able to make multiple simultaneous requests that, when finished, can return to the previous scope and change data accordingly. I considered using a database, but thought that it would end up being more complicated than necessary.
Ghommey: I don't completely understand [session_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php), how can I ensure that it fetches the correct session?

Comment: running php through regular old slow cgi does a complete setup and tear down of the interpretor and memory for each request. Zero execution remnants remain this way. Running php as an apache module however, doesn't *fully* wipe all memory, but most of it. I've run into issues where setting certain settings like locale don't get reset after a script execution, and are shared process wide. This was a long time ago, but the point is memory isn't totally wiped when running as an apache module, nor fast cgi. Many php extensions behave differently due to these differences

Comment: Found [session_name](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php), looks like $_SESSION will work. Thanks, @Ghommey.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

php doesn't work that way. its about run and forget.

you can save data between requests using userland shared memory extensions, for example: apc, xcache, memcached, etc.

or by using the session data array after calling session_start

> $_SESSION

don't think of php scripts like a java application in e.g. tomcat. standard php was not designed for that use case. php compiler works on-the-fly.

Comment: I found [session_name](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php) to be very helpful with this. Each file can share the same session_name, and all of the relevant data can be stored in the session object. This way, I can run an init file that sets up the session object, and then all of the related script files can use it accordingly.

Comment: @Monchoman45 well in my opinion sessions are not made to replace $GLOBALS or page caching if that is what you ment ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [shared memory](http://www.php.net/manual/en/shmop.examples-basic.php) for some of what you want, but Redis/Memcache are probably better bets.

Answer (score 0):

Let the server stay between requests, so will objects do:

- [appserver-in-php](https://github.com/indeyets/appserver-in-php) - Generic HTTP applications approach for PHP5.3+ (inspired by Rack and WSGI)

With well written applications that gives you more speed than APC, however it doesn't scale between users if you need to put on mutliple boxes (you still can use sticky sessions).